# What expression should I use in these situations?

Tags: american-english, expressions, informal-language, spoken-english

I'm studying in America but I'm having a hard time using proper expressions in proper situations..So I'm really nervous when I speak English..

1. When I order 2 meals and want to tell a staff that I want to put sauce in one and don't want to put sauce in the other, how can I say this shortly?
2. When I pay after having lunch and want to pay separately, is it okay to say 'We're gonna pay separately.' ?
3. Do I have to say 'you're welcome' to every single 'thank you'? Cause I find many Americans say thank you even though I don't really do something helpful for them. For example, teachers say thank you when I hand in my assignment which is so weird for me to hear thank you about it and I don't know what to say after hearing that.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! These should probably be three separate questions; you can [edit] this one to ask only #1, and ask two others for the other two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It' s OK. Relax. Remember to breathe.

1) Tell them to "Hold the sauce on the other." It means I don't want sauce on the other. It's common usage in a restaurant.

2) This is fine.

3) Americans respond a lot to non-verbal language such as nods of the head. Some cultures spend a lot of time in the morning saying "Good Morning..How are you..blah, blah." Most Americans are less formal than that. In the morning, "Hi" or "Good morning."

If you want to impress your teachers when you hand in an assignment say "Thank you!" right back at them, and meet their eye.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can I also say' Hold the milk on the other' when I don't want to put milk in only one cup of coffee?

Comment: @JoAnn - The best way to say that is to say that you want milk (or cream?) in one coffee, but you want the other coffee **black**. (See [what is black coffee](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/black_coffee).)

Answer (score 6):

For each of your situations in turn:

1) For the same meal being orders twice

> *(pattern)* **Two** ***somethings***, **one with sauce and the other without**
>   *Two hamburgers, one with ketchup and pickles and the other without*

2) For splitting the bill

> **We're gonna pay separately** *(this is fine)*
>   **We're going to** ***split*** **the bill**
>   **Can you** ***split*** **this on both cards**
>   **Could we get** ***separate checks*** *(can be said before ordering)*

It can be a nice gesture to tell your waiter **when you are ordering** that it will be two separate checks if you both intend to only pay for what you each order, otherwise you'd both just **split** the bill

3) After "thank you"

There are several things you can say or do after someone says "thank you" to you, it depends on the situation

> **You're welcome**  *(can never go wrong this this one)*
>   **No problem
>
>   Don't mention it
>
>   My pleasure**
>
> **Look forward to the next one** *(after handing in your assignment)*
>   **Can't wait for the next one**
>   **See you soon** *(in response to "thank you for coming")*

A simple non-verbal smile goes a long way.

Comment: +1 for "separate checks." (Incidentally, _separate checks_ and _split the bill_ might not mean the same thing. Let's say you order the house special and a Coke for $12, and I get an $8 cheeseburger and drink water. If we have _separate checks_, I'd get a bill for $8 and you'd get one for $12, but if we "split the bill," we might just each pay $10.)

Answer (score 5):

You're right about "thank you" – not every "thank you" needs a "you're welcome."

Besides "You're welcome," other options (depending on the situation) might included:

- **No problem**. (*when you've done something very small to help the other person*)
- **Don't mention it**.  (*when you've done something helpful, but you don't want the other person to make a big fuss over it*)
- **Thank you!** (*when someone else has served you in some way, such as at a store or restaurant*)

In the case where you describe – a teacher accepting your assignment – there's really no need to reply. A smile is just fine. If you really feel like you want to say something, though, you could always say something polite like:

- *I hope I did well!*

or:

- *That was an interesting assignment.*

However, I'd recommend **avoiding** such remarks unless you really mean them. Don't tell a teacher that an assignment was challenging when it was really easy, or interesting if you found it boring. Most people don't appreciate comments like that unless they are sincere.